# Function Overloading with const

Tags: c++, overloading

```
struct A
{
    void fn(double a) const {}
    void fn(int a){}
};
int main()
{
    A().fn(1.);
}
```

For the above mentioned function why does the compiler produce an ambiguity; Both the types are different.

Comment: error C2666: 'A::print': 2 overloads have similar conversions;;;could be 'void A::print(int)';;;could be void A::print(double) const';;; while trying to match the argument list '(double)';;;qualification adjustment (const/volatile) may be causing the ambiguity

Comment: That's a much more useful error message than what GCC gives:  "ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you like to pass an `int` only to a non-const `A`?

There are two parameters to each member function, `this` and `a`. So you require a `const A*` for `this` and `double`for `a`, or non-const `A*` and `int`.

And the call doesn't fully match either alternative, as you have non-const `A`and `double`. So the compiler can either convert `A()` to `const A`, or `double`to `int`. And it cannot decide which is the best.

Comment: But how come if there is only a const function; it converts from non const to const; What is the main advantage of this ambiguity?

Comment: If there is just one choice, that will be the one called. Now there are two overloads, and the compiler must select the best match. And they are equally close - one parameter is an exact match and the other one needs a conversion. And in a real program this is easily fixed by adding a `const` to the second function.